# Precompiled headers with ICC 16.0

Tags: c++, precompiled-headers, icc

We recently migrated our solution from VS2012/ICC 13.0 (*VS = Visual Studio, ICC = Intel C++ Compiler or Intel Parallel Studio*) to **VS2015 update 3 / ICC 16.0 update 3**. My question is about the use of precompiled headers (*pch*) with ICC 16.0.

Before, we used **/Yu** on a given project in order to use a *pch* created from a source file for which we set **/Yc**. No problem with ICC 13.0

Now, for the same project with 16.0, we get

*error: unable to obtain mapped memory (see pch_diag.txt)*

*compilation aborted for "file_used_to_create_pch.cpp (code 4)*

To solve the problem I had to deactivate the use of *pch*. So,

1. Did someone else face the same problem?
2. If so, is it a problem with my settings or is it a bug with ICC 16.0 update 3?

Not using *pch* doesn't bother me that much but I would like to have more information about this problem.

Thank you if you have any hint/info!

---

**EDIT 1**

*pch_diag.txt*

> === Dumping Virtual Address Space Info ===
>
> Page size: 0000000000001000
>
> Minimum application address: 0000000000010000
>
> Maximum application address: 000007FFFFFEFFFF
>
> Base Address: 0000000000034000 Region Size: 000000000000C000
>
> Base Address: 0000000000041000 Region Size: 000000000000F000
>
> Base Address: 0000000000051000 Region Size: 000000000000F000
>
> Base Address: 0000000000061000 Region Size: 000000000000F000
>
> Base Address: 0000000000071000 Region Size: 000000000000F000
>
> Base Address: 00000000000E7000 Region Size: 0000000000009000
>
> ...
>
> Base Address: 000007FFFFFD9000 Region Size: 0000000000005000
>
> Largest Region: 00000001423E1000 size: 000007FD7B54F000

**Compiler options:**

/Yu"CommonIncludes.h" /MP /GS /Qopenmp_stubs /GA /W3 /Qdiag-disable:"4251" /Qdiag-disable:"4275" /Qdiag-disable:"4996" /Qdiag-disable:"11074" /Qdiag-disable:"11075" /Zc:wchar_t /I"....\libraries\xyz\include" /I"..\Project1" /I"....\libraries\abc\include" /I"....\libraries\def" /I"....\libraries\ghi" /I".\" /I"....\libraries\jkl\include" /Zi /Od /Qdiag-disable:"cpu-dispatch" /Fd"D:\BETA\OutDir\x64\Debug\ThisLibrary.pdb" /fp:fast=2 /D "_DEBUG_MSG" /D "_DEBUG" /D "WIN32" /D "PSAPI_VERSION=1" /D "NOMINMAX" /D "TARGET_NAME=\"ThisLibrary\"" /D "_WINDLL" /Qstd=c++11 /Zc:forScope /MDd /Fa"D:\BETA\ThisLibrary\lib\x64\Debug\" /EHsc /Qcilk-serialize /nologo /Fo"D:\BETA\ThisLibrary\lib\x64\Debug\" /Qprof-dir "D:\BETA\ThisLibrary\lib\x64\Debug\" /Fp"D:\BETA\ThisLibrary\lib\x64\Debug\ThisLibrary.pch"

Comment: [This article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/unable-to-obtain-mapped-memory) suggests to me that it is a bug in the compiler, namely that it does not properly support ASLR. That fails to explain why it *used* to work with ICC 13, though, since that's an old article. Hard to guess at what else might be causing this. What did `pch_diag.txt` contain? What other compiler switches are you using (i.e., what is your complete command line)? Other sources online suggest that passing `/YX` could be the source of the issue.

Comment: @Code Gray See Edit 1 for pch_diag.txt and compiler options.